# How to replicate function on similar divs with same function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

If I have li which contains a function (duplicate on keyup), how can I replicate that same function to a clone of that same li.

> this is the element (li, better said), which will be constantly duplicated

```
<li class="main-item">
 <div class="header-item fwidth">
 <div>
  <h1 class="duplicado fleft"></h1>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div id="internal-items-2" class="collapse collapsible-item">
  <div>
   <input type="text" value="" class="duplicante nombre-item">
  </div>
 </div>
</li>
```

> this is the duplicate on keyup function, which produces text on the H1 element according to what is written on the input

```
$(function() {
    $('.duplicante').on('keyup', function() {
        var text = $(this).val();
        $('.duplicado').text(text);
    });
});
```

How to make that function works for each duplicated li element?
[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/s16vds6n/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is to updated the individual headers upon `keyup`.

One way to do it would be like this:

```
$(function() {
  $('.duplicante').on('keyup', function() {
    var text = $(this).val();
    $(this).closest('li').find('.duplicado').text(text);
  });
});
```

here is the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/s16vds6n/1/

Comment: damn! like a charm! genius :)